# how to use array values to display a specific image to screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that i have populated with corridor names.

```
corridorPath = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
```

What I want to do is loop through the array and for every corridor there will be an image of the corridor associated to it. 
So if the path was c1->c2->c4 the output will be an image of corridor 1 first and then an image of corridor 2 and then corridor 4. Using buttons to click through them.

My problem is i don't know how to use array values to change the image displayed.

my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"></head>
<h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:80px"> IT Carlow Orientation App </h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <form onsubmit="return rrr()" method ="POST">
  What room is closest to you: <input id="from" type="text"><br><br>
  What room do you want to go to : <input id="to" type="text"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
function rrr(){
    var INFINITY = 1/0;

function DirectedGraph(){
  this.vertices = {};
  this.addVertex = function(name, edges){
    edges = edges || null;
    this.vertices[name] = edges;
  }
}

function findSmallest(dist, q) { 
  var min = Infinity;
  var minNode;

  for (var node in q) {
    if (dist[node] <= min) {
      min = dist[node]
      minNode = node;
    }
  }

  delete q[minNode]
  return minNode;
}

function djikstra(graph, startVertex) { 
  var dist = {};
  var prev = {};
  var q = {};
  var shortestPaths = {};

  for (var vertex in graph.vertices) {
    dist[vertex] = INFINITY;
    prev[vertex] = null;
    q[vertex] = graph.vertices[vertex];
    shortestPaths[vertex] = [];
  }

  dist[startVertex] = 0;

  while (Object.keys(q).length !== 0) {
    var smallest = findSmallest(dist, q);
    var smallestNode = graph.vertices[smallest] 
    //searches for the vertex u in the vertex set Q that has the least dist[smallest] value.

    for (var neighbor in smallestNode) {
      var alt = dist[smallest] + smallestNode[neighbor];
      //smallestNode[neighbor] is the distance between smallest and neighbor
      if (alt < dist[neighbor]) {
        dist[neighbor] = alt
        prev[neighbor] = smallest
      }
    }
  }

  getShortestPaths(prev, shortestPaths, startVertex, dist)

  return {
    shortestPaths: shortestPaths,
    shortestDistances: dist
  }
}

function getShortestPaths(previous, shortestPaths, startVertex, dist) { debugger
  for (var node in shortestPaths) {
    var path = shortestPaths[node];

    while(previous[node]) {
      path.push(node);
      node = previous[node];
    }

    //gets the starting node in there as well if there was a path from it
    if (dist[node] === 0) {
      path.push(node);
    } 
    path.reverse();
  }
}

var graph = new DirectedGraph();

//graph.addVertex('S', {V: 1, W: 4});
//graph.addVertex('W', {T: 3});
//graph.addVertex('V', {W: 2, T: 6});
//graph.addVertex('T');

graph.addVertex('c1', {c2: 1, c3: 1, c7: 1});
graph.addVertex('c2', {c1: 1, c6: 1});
graph.addVertex('c3', {c1: 1, c4: 1});
graph.addVertex('c4', {c3: 1, c5: 1});
graph.addVertex('c5', {c4: 1, c6: 1});
graph.addVertex('c6', {c2: 1, c5: 1});
graph.addVertex('c7', {c1: 1, c8: 1, c13: 1, c14: 1});
graph.addVertex('c8', {c7: 1, c9: 1});
graph.addVertex('c9', {c8: 1, c10: 1, c11: 1});
graph.addVertex('c10', {c9: 1});
graph.addVertex('c11', {c9: 1, c12: 1});
graph.addVertex('c12', {c11: 1});
graph.addVertex('c13', {c7: 1, c32: 1, c35: 1});
graph.addVertex('c14', {c7: 1, c22: 1, c15: 1});
graph.addVertex('c15', {c14: 1, c16: 1, c18: 1});
graph.addVertex('c16', {c15: 1, c17: 1});
graph.addVertex('c17', {c16: 1});
graph.addVertex('c18', {c15: 1, c19: 1, c26: 1});
graph.addVertex('c19', {c18: 1, c20: 1, c27: 1});
graph.addVertex('c20', {c19: 1, c21: 1});
graph.addVertex('c21', {c20: 1});
graph.addVertex('c22', {c14: 1, c23: 1, c26: 1});
graph.addVertex('c23', {c22: 1, c24: 1});
graph.addVertex('c24', {c23: 1, c25: 1});
graph.addVertex('c25', {c24: 1});
graph.addVertex('c26', {c18: 1, c22: 1});
graph.addVertex('c27', {c19: 1, c28: 1});
graph.addVertex('c28', {c27: 1, c29: 1});
graph.addVertex('c29', {c28: 1, c30: 1});
graph.addVertex('c30', {c29: 1, c31: 1});
graph.addVertex('c31', {c30: 1});
graph.addVertex('c32', {c13: 1, c33: 1});
graph.addVertex('c33', {c32: 1, c34: 1});
graph.addVertex('c34', {c33: 1});
graph.addVertex('c35', {c13: 1, c36: 1});
graph.addVertex('c36', {c35: 1});


var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
var dest = document.getElementById('from').value;


var obj = {"A100": 1,"A102": 2, "A200": 3, "A201": 4, "A204": 5, "A205": 6, "A206": 7, "A207": 8, "A210": 9,
                            "A211": 10, "A212": 11, "A213": 12, "A216": 13, "A306": 14, "A307": 15, "A310": 16, "A311": 17,
                            "A312": 18, "A313": 19, "F208": 20, "F209": 21, "F210":22, "D404": 23, "D407": 24, "D410A": 25,
                            "D411": 26, "D410": 27, "D412": 28, "D413": 29, "D422": 30, "D426": 31, "D416": 32, "D417": 33,
                            "D501": 34, "D521": 35, "D522": 36, "D523": 37, "D502": 38, "D503": 39, "D504": 40, "D505": 41,
                            "D506": 42, "D507": 43, "D530": 44, "D531": 45, "D532": 46, "D508": 47, "D509": 48, "D510": 49,
                            "D511": 50, "D512": 51, "D513": 52, "D526": 53, "D527": 54, "D516": 55, "D517": 56, "D518": 57,
                            "C182": 58, "C185": 59, "C135": 60, "C136": 61, "C172": 62, "C173": 63, "C174": 64, "C175": 65,
                            "C176": 66, "C169": 67, "C170": 68, "C156": 69, "C149": 70, "C160": 71, "C162": 72, "C114": 73,
                            "C116": 74, "C118": 75, "C113": 76, "C115": 77, "C109": 78, "C101": 79, "C102": 80, "C104": 81,
                            "C105": 82, "C314": 83, "C316": 84, "C318": 85, "C321": 86, "C324": 87, "C325": 88, "C326": 89,
                            "C338": 90, "C339": 91, "C341": 92, "C344": 93, "C347": 94, "C348": 95, "C349": 96, "C350": 97,
                            "C351": 98, "C201": 99, "C202": 100, "C303": 101, "C305": 102, "C234": 103, "C233": 104,"C232": 105,
                            "C229": 106, "C228": 107, "C226": 108, "C225": 109, "C223": 110, "C220": 111, "C219": 112, "C218": 113,
                            "C210": 114, "C209": 115, "C208": 116, "C207": 117, "C206": 118, "C248": 119, "C246": 120, "C239": 121,
                            "C238": 122, "G101": 123, "G102": 124, "G103": 125, "G104": 126, "G106": 127, "G107": 128, "G108": 129,
                            "K102": 130, "K103": 131, "K104": 132, "K105": 133, "K106": 134, "K114": 135, "K115": 136, "K117": 137,
                            "K118": 138, "K202": 139, "K203": 140, "K204": 141, "K206": 142, "K207": 143, "K209": 144, "K210": 145,
                            "K221": 146, "K222": 147, "K302": 148, "K304": 149, "K305": 150, "K318": 151, "K319": 152, "K320": 153,
                            "K321": 154, "E801": 155, "E802": 156, "E803": 157, "E804": 158, "E805": 159, "E806": 160, "E807": 161,
                            "E808": 162, "E901": 163, "E902": 164, "E903": 165, "E904": 166, "E905": 167, "E906": 168, "E907": 169,
                            "E908": 170, "E909": 171, "E910": 172, "E911": 173, "L106": 174, "L107": 175, "L108": 176, "L109": 177,
                            "L110": 178, "L111": 179, "L112": 180, "L113": 181, "L114": 182, "L115": 183, "L116": 184, "L117": 185,
                            "L205": 186, "L206": 187, "L207": 188, "L208": 189, "L209": 190, "L210": 191, "L211": 192, "L212": 193,
                            "L213": 194, "L214": 195, "L215": 196, "L216": 197, "L217": 198};

                    x = obj[to];

                    if (x > 0 && x <= 19){
                        if( x >= 1 && x <= 2)
                        {
                            to = "c16";
                        }
                        else if(x >= 3 && x <= 19)
                        {
                            to = "c17";
                        }
                    }
                    else if (x >= 20 && x <= 22){
                        to = "c21";
                    }
                    else if (x >= 23 && x <= 57){
                        if( x >= 23 && x <= 26)
                        {
                            to = "c6";
                        }
                        else if(x >= 27 && x <= 31)
                        {
                            to = "c5";
                        }
                        else if(x >= 32 && x <= 33)
                        {
                            to = "c3";
                        }

                    }
                    else if (x >= 58 && x <= 122){
                        if( x >= 58 && x <= 59)
                        {
                            to = "c9";
                        }
                        else if(x >= 60 && x <= 61)
                        {
                            to = "c10";
                        }
                        else if(x >= 62 && x <= 69)
                        {
                            to = "c11";
                        }   
                        else if(x >= 70 && x <= 72)
                        {
                            to = "c12";
                        }                       
                    }
                    else if (x >= 123 && x <= 129){
                        to = "c31";
                    }
                    else if (x >= 130 && x <= 154){
                        to = "c36";
                    }
                    else if (x >= 155 && x <= 173){
                        to = "c24";
                    }
                    else if (x >= 174 && x <= 198){
                        to = "c33";
                    }

                    y = obj[dest];

                    if (y > 0 && y <= 19){
                        if( y >= 1 && y <= 2)
                        {
                            dest = "c16";
                        }
                        else if(y >= 3 && y <= 19)
                        {
                            dest = "c17";
                        }
                    }
                    else if (y >= 20 && y <= 22){
                        dest = "c21";
                    }
                    else if (y >= 23 && y <= 57){
                        if( y >= 23 && y <= 26)
                        {
                            dest = "c6";
                        }
                        else if(y >= 27 && y <= 31)
                        {
                            dest = "c5";
                        }
                        else if(y >= 32 && y <= 33)
                        {
                            dest = "c3";
                        }

                    }
                    else if (y >= 58 && y <= 122){
                        if( y >= 58 && y <= 59)
                        {
                            dest = "c9";
                        }
                        else if(y >= 60 && y <= 61)
                        {
                            dest = "c10";
                        }
                        else if(y >= 62 && y <= 69)
                        {
                            dest = "c11";
                        }   
                        else if(y >= 70 && y <= 72)
                        {
                            dest = "c12";
                        }                       
                    }
                    else if (y >= 123 && y <= 129){
                        dest = "c31";
                    }
                    else if (y >= 130 && y <= 154){
                        dest = "c36";
                    }
                    else if (y >= 155 && y <= 173){
                        dest = "c24";
                    }
                    else if (y >= 174 && y <= 198){
                        dest = "c33";
                    }

var result = djikstra(graph, dest);

switch(to){
  case "c1":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c1;
  break;
  case "c2":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c2;
  break;
  case "c3":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c3;
  break;
  case "c4":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c4;
  break;
  case "c5":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c5;
  break;
  case "c6":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c6;
  break;
  case "c7":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c7;
  break;
  case "c8":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c8;
  break;
  case "c9":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c9;
  break;
  case "c10":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c10;
  break;
  case "c11":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c11;
  break;
  case "c12":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c12;
  break;
  case "c13":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c13;
  break;
  case "c14":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c14;
  break;
  case "c15":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c15;
  break;
  case "c16":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c16;
  break;
  case "c17":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c17;
  break;
  case "c18":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c18;
  break;
  case "c19":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c19;
  break;
  case "c20":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c20;
  break;
  case "c21":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c21;
  break;
  case "c22":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c22;
  break;
  case "c23":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c23;
  break;
  case "c24":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c24;
  break;
  case "c25":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c25;
  break;
  case "c26":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c26;
  break;
  case "c27":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c27;
  break;
  case "c28":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c28;
  break;
  case "c29":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c29;
  break;
  case "c30":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c30;
  break;
  case "c31":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c31;
  break;
  case "c32":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c32;
  break;
  case "c33":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c33;
  break;
  case "c34":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c34;
  break;
  case "c35":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c35;
  break;
  case "c36":
    s = result.shortestPaths.c36;
  break;
  default:
    s = null;
  break;
}

 var corridorpath = "";
 var corridorPath = new Array();

 if(s != null){
  for( x in s){
    var i = 0;
    corridorPath[i] = s[x];
    i++;
    alert(corridorPath);
  }
 }
 else{
   corridorpath = "Please enter a valid room number";
 }
 //alert(corridorpath);

 var obj1 = {"c16": "images/c16.jpg", "c15": "images/c15.jpg","c18": "images/c18.jpg", "c19": "images/c19.jpg",
            "c20": "images/c20.jpg", "c21": "images/c21.jpg"};
 var corr = "c16";
 pic = obj1[corr];
 alert(pic)
};
```

First off I know my coding is horrible! My level of programming is low so try not to let that distract you...

Comment: If you add your HTML and more of your JS, it would help answerers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows, assuming `corridorPath` contains addresses of the images you want to display:

```js
var corridorPath = [
  'path/to/image1.jpg', 
  'path/to/image2.jpg', 
  'path/to/image3.jpg', 
];

// find the element in the document where you want
// to put the images
var pathEl = document.getElementById('path');

// iterate over the array with image srcs
corridorPath.forEach(function (corridor) {
  // create <img /> element
  var imageEl = document.createElement('img');
  
  // set img's src and alt text
  imageEl.src = corridor;
  imageEl.alt = "Image description here";
  
  // append img element to the target element
  pathEl.appendChild(imageEl);
});
```

```html
<div id="path"></div>
```

Comment: how could i implement this using a map object. my map object looks like this    |  var obj1 = {"c16": "images/c16.jpg", "c15": "images/c15.jpg","c18": "images/c18.jpg", "c19": "images/c19.jpg",
   "c20": "images/c20.jpg", "c21": "images/c21.jpg"};

Comment: adding to above, i don't have an array with the image paths but i use a map to assign each corridor its image. so how could i call the map object in place of calling on the array in your example?